# eye color gene probability problem

Tags: probability

I saw this question asked By a user by the name of Anne. The user had answers to two of the three and wanted an explanation of the third part (not including the third part as it is not what I'm concerned with). Could anyone please explain me as how the user has solved the 2nd part? (solved below, by the user itself)?

The color of a person’s eyes is determined by a single pair of genes. If they are both blue-eyed genes, then the person will have blue eyes; if they are both brown-eyed genes, then the person will have brown eyes; and if one of them is a blue-eyed gene and the other a brown-eyed gene, then the person will have brown eyes. (Because of the latter fact, we say that the brown-eyed gene is dominant over the blue-eyed one.) A newborn child independently receives one eye gene from each of its parents, and the gene it receives from a parent is equally likely to be either of the two eye genes of that parent.

Suppose that Smith and both of his parents have brown eyes, but Smith’s sister has blue eyes. (a) What is the probability that Smith possesses a blue-eyed gene?

if Smith's sister has blue eyes , Smith's parents have both the genes Blue-Brown.

The possible cases for Smith are: Brown-Brown, Blue-Brown, Brown-Blue and the positive cases: Blue-Brown, Brown-Blue

$$p=2/3$$
(b) Suppose that Smith’s wife has blue eyes. What is the probability that their first child will have blue eyes?

$$p(\text{the first child has blue eyes})=p(B|\text{Brown−Brown})∗p(\text{Brown−Brown})+p(B|\text{Blue−Blue})∗p(\text{Blue−Blue})+p(B|\text{Blue−Brown})∗p(\text{Blue−Brown})+p(B|\text{Brown-Blue})∗p(\text{Brown-Blue})=0\times\frac{1}{3}+1\times 0+\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: Please format your math with MathJax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know about it and was looking for ways to format my question. So thanks a lot for sharing this, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Let b indicate the blue-eye allele and B the brown-eye allele.

Brown eyes are dominant over blue eyes, so a brown-eye phenotype indicates a genotype of BB, Bb, or bB.

A blue-eye phenotype can only indicate the genotype bb.

As Smith's wife exhibits the blue-eye phenotype, her genotype is bb, and so the child will have one b allele from its mother.

Thus, the probability that the child has blue eyes is the probability that it inherits a b allele from Smith.

So, $$\begin{aligned}\mathbb{P}(\text{child has blue eyes}) &= \mathbb{P}(\text{Smith contributes b allele})\\
&=\mathbb{P}(\text{Smith is BB})\mathbb{P}(\text{Smith contributes b} \mid \text{Smith is BB})\\
&+\mathbb{P}(\text{Smith is Bb})\mathbb{P}(\text{Smith contributes b} \mid \text{Smith is Bb})\\
&+\mathbb{P}(\text{Smith is bB})\mathbb{P}(\text{Smith contributes b} \mid \text{Smith is bB})\\
&+\mathbb{P}(\text{Smith is bb})\mathbb{P}(\text{Smith contributes b} \mid \text{Smith is bb})\\
&= \frac 1 3 \cdot 0 + \frac 1 3 \cdot \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 3 \cdot \frac 1 2 + 0 \cdot 1 = \frac 1 3
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. Your answer now makes it quite clear.